# In clojure, how does one thrush through a list of functions?

Tags: clojure

In clojure, I would like to push a thrush value through a list of functions, but I'm not sure how to do so in an idiomatic way. The idea is that I will have a list containing an unknown number of functions, and I'd like to take advantage of the variadic nature of thrush.

So, something like this...

```
(->> 1 inc inc inc)
; 4

(->> 1 '(inc inc inc))
; does not work, of course
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `comp` is the most idiomatic option here, though it will have prefix syntax instead. This is also more in keeping with normal Clojure (fn args) notation.

```
=> ((comp inc inc inc) 1)
4
```

Combine it with the idiomatic `apply` if a function normally takes variadic arguments, but you want to feed it a collection.

```
=> ((apply comp (repeat 3 inc)) 1)
4
```

Be aware though it threads from right to left

```
=> ((comp str inc inc inc) 1)
"4"
=> ((comp inc inc inc str ) 1)
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

This also complies more with Clojure/Lisp s-expressions.

If you want more 'easy' human readable notation, Arthur Ulfeldt's answer is perfecly acceptable, and a nice example of reduce and functional programming. Using it 'as is' might get in the way of getting acquainted with the 'simplicity' of s-expressions though..

Be careful with macro's !

The reason why -> and ->> are macro's is that they actively rewrite forms, so you can use normally incomplete argument notation like `(filter odd?)` in their scope without having to resort to overuse of `partial`. This can't be done with normal function compostition.

Best learn to make the most of [normal function composition](http://clojuredocs.org/quickref/Clojure%20Core#FunctionsGeneral) before turning to macro's. There's a lot of pitfalls in them for the unaccustomed, and should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 6):

reduce does this nicely in this context

```
user> (reduce #(%2 %1) 1 [inc inc inc])
4
user> (defn thrush [val funs] (reduce #(%2 %1) val funs))
#'user/thrush
user> (thrush 1 [inc inc inc dec])
3
```

When possible sitck to functions over macros for such things

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
user=> (def my-fns [inc inc inc])
#'user/my-fns
user=> (->> 1 ((apply comp my-fns)))
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do this:

```
 (defmacro thrush-list [x flist] `(->> ~x ~@flist))
 (thrush-list 1 [inc inc inc])
 ; 4
```

Comment: This does not work at all - unless the list is a literal, known at compile time, in which case, you would just use ordinary `->` or `->>`.